# Mongo 2.6.12 VS Mongo 4.0 benchmark

Tags: benchmarking, mongodb

I have problem, I use the old 2.6.12 version of mongodb on a new computer and it does not show high speed results and I do not know why. Mongo 2.6.12 doesn’t even try to use my computer at 100% using only 40%.

[see Mongo 2.6.12 benchmark db.update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSiCQ.png) it only 40% cpu
[see Mongo 4.0.10 benchmark db.update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytiBH.png) it use 100% cpu

How to make Mongo 2.6.12 work on 100%

Answer (score 0):

There have been [five major releases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/) (and many minor) in the five years since MongoDB 2.6 was released. Successive MongoDB releases have included many significant improvements such as a new storage engine ([WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)) which has features like document-level concurrency, data compression, and index prefix compression. WiredTiger's design goals include more efficient use of I/O, higher utilisation of multiple CPU cores, and requiring less hardware for a given workload.

It is expected that WiredTiger will generally have much better throughput and resource utilisation for a multi-threaded workload. For example, see the [Performance Testing MongoDB 3.0](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-testing-mongodb-30-part-1-throughput-improvements-measured-ycsb) blog post series. The original MMAPv1 storage engine has database-level locking and other design limitations that can only be addressed with an alternative storage engine. WiredTiger has been the default storage engine for new deployments since MongoDB 3.2; the MMAPv1 storage engine was deprecated in MongoDB 4.0 and will be removed in the upcoming MongoDB 4.2 server release.

Without seeing the details of your `testcpu.js` benchmark, I would assume that it is running into one of the concurrency limitations of MongoDB 2.6 that has since been addressed. However, that detail is moot since MongoDB 2.6 reached end of life in October, 2016. I would strongly recommend upgrading to an actively supported version of MongoDB server (currently 3.4 or newer).